# xml parser terminated Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I want to pars my xml file in objective-c, but I got an error

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
'[<Presentation1Name 0x74592f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
coding-compliant for the key slide.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c93012 0x10d0e7e 0x1d1bfb1 0xb7d711 0xafeec8 0xafe9b7 0x5129 0xbb11c7 0x48c65ee 
 0x48c5f07 0xbaf6d2 0x2008 0x157b7 0x15da7 0x16fab 0x28315 0x2924b 0x1acf8 0x1beedf9 
0x1beead0 0x1c08bf5 0x1c08962 0x1c39bb6 0x1c38f44 0x1c38e1b 0x167da 0x1865c 0x1e5d 
0x1d85)

libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

ment to lowercase presentation , I don"t have an error bu I can not pars the label="presentation1" but when I change it to Upercase P -> Presentation I can pars it but with terminated process

Would you please give me some hint for finding the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aPresentation is your own class so its hard to know exactly what its made up of.  However your error is coming up when you try to do (unless there is more code that your not showing) :

```
[aPresentation setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
```

here you are saying you have a property in the object aPresentation with the name elementName; specifically your error is saying there is no property with the name "slide"

Is there a property (variable) with the name "slide"?  Apparently not.

I would suggest hard coding what the elementName is because apparently they are not lining up with your class.

According to the xml your property (within aPresentation) should be named "slides" so either rename the property in your class to slides or just change element name into what you know it to be.

```
[aPresentation setValue:currentElementValue forKey:@"slideLabel"];
```

some of this is guess work without seeing the class structure of Presentation1Name

I would also like to point out some conventions you are not following which makes this code very hard to read.  Property names should be capitalized (first letter), including numbers in your class names is ok but not used very often and probably not needed in this case.  you are checking if the elementName is Slides or slide and really that stuff shouldnt change and you should be able to remove one of those statements.  i would also recommend to always use brackets, some of your else statments dont